# Infinite sequences/ordered tuples of proper classes in NBG

Tags: set-theory

The question is originally from math stack exchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4867526/defining-ordered-tuples-of-arbitrary-length-in-nbg).

Basically, what I am asking is if we can define ordered tuples of proper classes in *NBG*. My idea, for finite tuples of proper classes, was to define it as the set $\{0\} \times X_0 \cup \{1\} \times X_1 \times ... \times \{n\} \times X_n$. Here I am not assuming $(X_i)_{i < n+1}$ as an encoded structure since that would assume the conclusion. However, we can define this using recursion. The empty tuple is the empty set(i.e. $()=\emptyset$) and $(X_0, X_1, ..., X_n) = (X_0, ..., x_{n-1}) \cup \{n\} \times X_n$.

Now I would intuitively define $(X_\alpha)_{\alpha < \beta}$ for $ \beta $ an ordinal, by transfinite recursion, by taking $(X_\alpha)_{\alpha < \beta + 1} = (X_\alpha)_{\alpha < \beta} \cup \{\beta\} \times X_{\beta}$ and if $\beta$ is a limit ordinal, then $(X_\alpha)_{\alpha < \beta} = \bigcup_{\alpha < \beta} \left( (X_{\gamma})_{\gamma < \alpha} \right)$. However, there is a problem with the limit ordinals, since I am taking the "infinite union", the sum class, which is basically the union of its members, so it would require that $X_a \in T$, which is impossible since $X_a$ is a proper class.

However, I have also found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383470/ordered-pairs-in-nbg-set-theory?rq=1) answer on stack exchange that uses exactly this method and it I don't know whether what I said above is correct or not.

Comment: You strategy seems correct, except for the union case you need to define it in a way that doesn't require the $X_\gamma$'s to be elements, since they can't if they were proper classes. Define: $\bigcup_{\alpha< \beta}((X_\gamma)_{\gamma < \alpha})= \{\langle \alpha, x \rangle \in X_\alpha  \mid \alpha < \beta \}$

Comment: As a general matter, recursions defining classes by induction (even for length $\omega$) cannot be undertaken in NBG. For example, the definition of first-order truth via the Tarski recursion is a recursion of length $\omega$, yet in NBG it is consistent that there is no class truth predicate. One is using the principle known as elementary transfinite recursion (ETR) when making such definitions by recursion. This principle is provable in KM, but not NGB. Meanwhile, you don't need recursion at all here, if you have already the classes $X_\alpha$ in a way that is definable from $\alpha$.

Comment: You can read more about ETR in https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-symbolic-logic/article/abs/exact-strength-of-the-class-forcing-theorem/2295032404B1308A9D4D91065F514FA1 and related references.

Comment: I should have said "by recursion" not "by induction" in my first comment above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define infinite tuple of order $\omega$ as a subclass of the Kuratowski-Cartesian product of $\omega$ and some class, having the class of all first projections of elements of it (aka preimage; domain) being $\omega$ itself (if the empty set is not an entry, otherwise we don't need the latter condition but we need the domain which is already a subclass of $\omega$ to be of order type $\omega$).

Now we define projections of a tuple $t$ as:

$x \text{ is the } \alpha \text{ entry  of } t \iff x=\{y \mid \langle \alpha, y \rangle \in t \}$

Clearly $x,t$ can be proper classes!

Of course if you demand all entries to be proper classes, then you add the condition that every $\alpha \in \omega$ entry of $t$ is a proper class.

You can do that for any infinite ordinal $\lambda$ to get an infinite tuple of order $\lambda$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "Kuratowski-Cartesian product"? I am not an expert in the study of set theory.

Comment: @Shthephathord23, the Kuratowski-Cartesian product between classes $A$ and $B$ (denoted as $A \times B$) is the class of all Kuratowski-ordered pairs $\langle a,b \rangle$ where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. The Kuratowski ordered pair of $a$ and $b$ denoted as $\langle a,b \rangle$ is the set $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$. So, to write it formally: $A \times B = \{ \langle a, b\rangle \mid a \in A \land b \in B \}$

Comment: ok, but I still don't understand the construction. From what I can follow, is the class of all first projection the domain(i.e. $\{ x \vert (\exists y)( (x, y) \in A \times B) \}$)?

Comment: @Shthephathord23, Yes! Since you want an infinite tuple of proper classes, then each entry is a proper class and thus nonempty, so you need that domain to be $\omega$ itself, where $\omega$ is the set of all  naturals.

Comment: So, what I am understanding is that if we have some class of values, call it $C$(i conceptually think of it as the "union" of all my outputs, I know this is wrong since we can't do sum classes of proper classes) we can take any ordinal $\alpha$ and if we want a $\beta$-indexed tuple then it would be $\alpha \times X \cap \beta \times X$? And I guess this method does generalize for tuples indexed by a proper class, since we can take $On \times X$ and we can talk about any tuple indexed by a proper subclass of $On$. Here $On = \{ x \mid Ord(x)\}$(i.e. $On$ is the class of all ordinals).

Comment: Your answer does really answer my question, but I would like to give you some background as to what I am actually trying to do. I want tuples of arbitrary length(i guess with the observation above, even proper-class length) of proper classes, because I actually want to define arbitrary unions and arbitrary generalized Cartesian products of families of proper classes and I thought that defining a tuple was the way to begin. But, talking outside the formal language, the definition above, assumes we have "the union" already figured out, and then we partition it accordingly in tuples.

Comment: However, what I have called "union class" could be defined easily as $\{ x \mid (\exists \alpha)(P(\alpha, x))\}$, so it is not an issue. Your answer is very helpful, but please confirm to me whether or not can we index tuples by proper classes, such as I have done with $On$ and point out why not if that's the case. Either way the answer was helpful.

Comment: @Shthephathord23. Yes you can have a tuple of order $On$ itself. Of course $On$ is the class of all set ordinals, and not the class of all ordinals, since $On$ itself is an ordinal and it is a proper class. Remember you can speak of tuples of proper classes as long as its order is $\leq On$, but there are more proper classes than sets! This is known in MK. You can indeed define arbitrary unions along tuples but those tuples cannot exceed $On$ in length. Of course there are some extensions of MK that states existence of well ordering over all proper classes, but this is another issue.

Comment: @Shthephathord23, what is $P$ in $ \{ x \mid (\exists \alpha)(P(\alpha, x))\}$, does it mean "pair" standing for an ordered pair whose first projection is $\alpha$ and second projection is $x$. If this is it, then of course you can get unions this way, because each $\alpha$ index a class (whether set or not), and you get the union of all those indexed by ordinals that satisfy an arbitrary formula $\varphi$ for example.

Comment: Yes, that is what the predicate $P$ would mean, sorry for not mentioning.

Comment: But wouldn't the fact that all proper classes have the "same length" be provable from global choice(which is an axiom of NBG as it says on wikipedia), so then all proper classes have the same "cardinality"?

Comment: @Shthephathord23, Yes! That is correct. Because of global choice a proper class is a class of cardinality $On$. I'm speaking within MK and not NBG. But for although all proper classes are of the same cardinality, namely $On$, yet working in MK, there are more proper classes than sets. For example you cannot have a tuple of all proper classes, because the largest tuple you can have is of cardinality $On$ while you have more proper classes than elements of $On$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151707/discussion-between-shthephathord23-and-zuhair-al-johar).